# JSON view formatting [$Editor] en [$Modified] not visible

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I'm formatting the view of an entire list using JSON.

Using the following code, the date modified and editor are not visible.

`{"elmType": "span","txtContent": "[$Editor]"}`

Same problem with `[$Modified]`

Comment: Do you show Modilfied by in the view？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this JSON for test (it is working for me):

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
    "hideSelection": true,
    "hideColumnHeader": true,
    "rowFormatter": {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
            "class": "sp-row-card"
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                    "class": "sp-row-title"
                },
                "txtContent": "[$Modified]"
            },
            {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                    "class": "sp-row-title"
                },
                "txtContent": "[$Editor.email]"
            }
        ]
    }
    
}
```

**Note**:

In order to access the **Modified By** and **Modified** columns in JSON, it should be included in the list view.

You can include the column in list view from view settings like:

[image]

**official documentations**:

1. [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)
2. [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) - You can find supported functions and guidelines for JSON formatting in this link

The people field object has the following properties (with example values):

```
{
   "id": "122",
   "title": "Kalya Tucker",
   "email": "kaylat@contoso.com",
   "sip": "kaylat@contoso.com",
   "picture": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/kaylat_contoso_com_MThumb.jpg?t=63576928822",
   "department":"Human Resources",
   "jobTitle":"HR Manager"
}
```

Also, to convert the date columns in other formats, you can use `toLocaleDateString()` or `toLocaleString()` functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use:`[$Editor.title]` to show the editor name.